# Which tube station did Varney die in?

Tags: neil-gaiman, neverwhere

Varney, the self-described "finest bravo and guide in the Underland" was killed by Mr Croup and Mr Vandemar while hiding out in a deserted Underground station. This station was described as having a lift, and a spiral staircase:

> He reached the bottom of the steps next to the sign warning travelers
> that there were **259 steps** to the top, and only healthy people should
> even think about attempting it.

I know that Covent Garden tube has a sign like this, but has 193 steps. The location appears to be a real station, rather than a ghost one, as it is described as having ticket machines, and that the floor was regularly mopped (obliterating the blood stain that was the last mortal trace of Varney). Does the 259-step staircase correspond to a real underground station?

Comment: Hampstead has 320.

Comment: St. Paul's cathedral. The Whispering Gallery
Climb 259 steps up the dome and you will find The Whispering Gallery, which runs around the interior of the Dome. It gets its name from a charming quirk in its construction, which makes a whisper against its walls audible on the opposite side.

Comment: @jo1storm you might want to put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a real station, as the number of steps doesn't tally with any existing (or [closed](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/about-tfl/culture-and-heritage/londons-transport-a-history/london-underground/disused-underground-stations)) station.

The description does, however roughly tally with [Covent Garden Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covent_Garden_tube_station) which has a [spiral staircase of *193* steps](https://diamondgeezer.blogspot.com/2018/01/tubegym.html) and which for many years has had a prominent warning sign about the health of potential users.

[image]

It's worth noting that the spiral stair of St Paul's Cathedral famously has [259 steps leading to the Whispering Gallery](https://www.planetware.com/london/st-pauls-cathedral-eng-l-spal.htm#:%7E:text=There%20are%20259%20steps%20leading,total%20width%20of%20112%20feet.). It's possible that Neil got the two mixed up, accidentally or on purpose.

Comment: For the record, I did consider Hampstead with its 320 stairs as a possible location, but the staircase is a mixture of spiral and flights; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fb9WU13_lD8

Comment: It seems Hampstead is the deepest with 320 stairs, then Covent Garden with 193, and Belsize Park, Russell Square, and Goodge Street with 136. So no actual station has 259.